# Difference between "spoke" and "spoken" in English grammar

Tags: difference, verbs

I am really poor in English, especially in grammar.

What is the difference between *spoke* and *spoken*?

Answer (score 2):

Verbs in English have three forms: ***simple present***, ***simple past***, and ***past participle***. In the simple present tense, subjects and verbs must agree with one another in number (e.g. *He works.*, but *We work*), but you might already know that.

*Spoke* is the simple past form of *speak*. *Spoken* is the past participle form of *speak*. It is helpful to remember the three forms altogether: *speak*, *spoke*, *spoken*.

Most of the verbs in simple past and past participle forms will have *-ed* appended to its simple present form, for example, *work*, *worked*, *worked*.

However, there are many verbs that this simple rule cannot apply. They are called **irregular verbs**. You can find a list of irregular verbs in **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_irregular_verbs#List)**.

Comment: +1 Actually they have [**more forms**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/verb-forms/info), but those are the relevant ones here.

Comment: *Spoken* could also be an adjective, as in "the spoken word", in addition to a past participle as you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks you so much Damkerng and other too. Its' really helpful for me if you also add some example that demonstrate the use of spoke and spoken. Thanks for your reply it's really helpful for me

Comment: @asifaftab87 - Maybe next time you can add an example to your question. When you leave a question so open-ended, it's hard to give much of an answer. You might try reading [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for further information on how to ask a question that might get more answers, or more acceptance from the community.